# What does "Vulg." imply in the RAE Dictionary?

Tags: definiciones, dle, rae, abreviaturas, diccionarios

I am working my way through translating the song "Mi Noche Triste" and in the first verse I encountered (my emphasis)

> Y por eso **me encurdelo** pa' olvidarme de tu amor

I believe that for "me encurdelo", the root verb was conjugated to "encurdé".  In looking the conjugation up in the RAE dictionary, it points to [encurdarse](https://dle.rae.es/encurdarse?m=form) (so far so good)

It appears that this is a synonym of "emborracharse".  And the dictionary tags this as:

1. prnl - verbo pronominal
2. vulg. - vulgar

I understand the pronominal tag, but what is the implication of "vulgar".  I can guess that it has similar connotations as in English of unrefined, bad taste, common etc.  But that is an assumption on my part.  Thus:

1. What is the actual usage of "Vulg." by the RAE?
2. Is there a description of all of such terms in that dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Vulgar' has the same meaning as *vulgar* in English. You can find it in other entries such as ['follar'](https://dle.rae.es/follar#IAjld1n).

The description of all the abbreviations and signs is in the page [Abreviaturas y signos empleados](https://dle.rae.es/contenido/abreviaturas-y-signos-empleados) from the dle.RAE.es domain.

There you can find the one you refer to:

> - vulg.   vulgar

Also, and as you may have noticed, the explanation of each abbreviation shows when you hover the given abbreviation:

> [image]

Comment: Well hovering gives me the definition in Spanish, but if I don't know what that means, I'm still in the dark :D